# save cropped image with PHP

Tags: php, image, crop

I have this script which crops the image. How do i save it to the server?

```
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "pictures/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);





$imgSrc = 'pictures/' . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

//getting the image dimensions
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imgSrc);

//saving the image into memory (for manipulation with GD Library)
$myImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgSrc);

// calculating the part of the image to use for thumbnail
if ($width > $height) {
  $y = 0;
  $x = ($width - $height) / 2;
  $smallestSide = $height;
} else {
  $x = 0;
  $y = ($height - $width) / 2;
  $smallestSide = $width;
}

// copying the part into thumbnail
$thumbSize = 100;
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbSize, $thumbSize);
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $myImage, 0, 0, $x, $y, $thumbSize, $thumbSize,     $smallestSide, $smallestSide);

//final output
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($thumb);
```

As you can see i am able to output the image. However im not able to save it. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: I want to save any type of image AFTER i crop it. So basically it's the $thumb variable that needs to be saved at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the second argument, The second argument takes in the filename as argument and saves it in the specified path

```
imagejpeg($thumb, 'filename');
```

example

```
imagejpeg($thumb, 'uploads/yourfilename.jpg');
```

Comment: Do provide some explanation as well. It will be beneficial for learners!

Answer (score 0):

Use https://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file to save the file

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "dir/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
```

or use imagejpeg but then you have to stick to jpeg.